# How can I count all rows except duplicate entry of a column?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table having the following data:

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

Here I want number of row matching the following conditions:
1. forwarded_by = $loggedUser['id']
2. ticket id should be distinct 
Thus The above table has total 12 rows but there is a duplicate entry for ticket_id 2. So my expected output is 11.

I run a query

```
**SELECT COUNT(tr.id) as total FROM tracks tr WHERE  where tr.forwarded_by = " . $loggedUser['id'] GROUP BY tr.ticket_id**
```

This gives a count for every distinct ticket_id but I want to get total rows ignoring duplicate ticket_id. How should I modify the query?

Comment: Have you tried to use the `GROUP BY` operator?

Comment: Sorry, but why 11 if there is duplicates on 22 and 1 as well? I see 8 distinct `ticket_id`s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT tr.ticket_id ) AS total
FROM tracks tr
WHERE tr.forwarded_by =87
```

Answer (score 2):

You just want `count(distinct)` with no `group by`:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ticket_id) as total
FROM tracks tr
WHERE where tr.forwarded_by = " . $loggedUser['id'] ;
```

Note:  In a real application, you should be using parameterized queries rather than munging the query string.

EDIT:

Despite the description, it looks like distinctness is based on (at least) two columns, `issue_id` and `ticket_id`:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ticket_id, issue_id) as total
FROM tracks tr
WHERE where tr.forwarded_by = " . $loggedUser['id'] ;
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand what's the distinctness as well, but I don't think it is by both `ticket_id` and `issue_id`, since 22 has both equal just like 2 which was used as example. Also, `SELECT count(1) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ticket_id FROM tracks WHERE forwarded_by=?) t` might be a faster approach